# Svn cleanup error

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

```
Msg:Previous operation has not finished; run cleanup  if it was interrupted
```

I have this probem when I tryed to update a file.How Can I solve this problem?,I don't want to download all the java project again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to check out the project again, just do a

```
svn cleanup
```

from the command line, or if you use TortoiseSVN, just right click on the folder of the working copy, and select the Clean Up option (icon looks like a broom)...

Comment: Now I have this message :cleanup failed to process the following paths:............Can't to move ...... to ........Access is denied

Comment: Ok, it seems something has a lock on a file, or folder. I'd close Eclipse, exit all command line shells that are open, and all applications that might have anything open under in the working copy, and try again with the cleanup.